# Zxing.net generate qr code xamarin.android null reference

Tags: xamarin.android, zxing

I have a problem generating qr code. I used a sample from site:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-barcode-and-qr-code-in-xamarin-android/

I have used the exact same code as in the example but I got a null reference error at this line:

```cs
bitmapMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(message, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size);
```

In my project I have installed the next packages:

- `Zxing.net`
- `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat`
- `Xamarin.Essentials`
- `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material`

Debug info:
[image]

Does anyone have a clue why I am getting a null reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what a null reference is, but at this line everything is not null. So I guess something is happening within encode method. But am I missing something? Or is it because it's a newer version then the example?

Comment: `everything is not null` - please show that.

Comment: I edited my question and added the screenshot with the watcher. As you can see the null reference would be coming from within the encode method of the MultiFormatWriter but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I had done a simple demo and repeated the problem. But it just happends on the QRCode and the others work well. So you can try to post the issue to the developer of zxing package on the github.

Comment: Thank you @LiyunZhang-MSFT I will contact the developer of zxing package.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug inside the static initialization routines which occurs if some encodings (character sets) are missing. The next version (>0.16.7) will fix it.

Comment: Hi Michael do you have any idea when this fix is going to be deployed?

Comment: I'm working on it. It will take some time.

Comment: Btw. version 0.16.8 is released.

Comment: hi Michael, I have tested the code but I get the next error: BitMatrix/MultiFormatWriter/BarcodeFormat exists both in  zxing and zxing.portable. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Perhaps you added the nuget package ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net. Remove one of them or use a different alias instead of "global" for one of the references.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes that was my problem. I referenced a project and that project contained zxing.net.mobile. Thank you for your support. Is the zxing.net a big improvement if you compare this to zxing.net.mobile? I have been using zxing.net.mobile now but I was wondering if the zxing.net a better version is?

Comment: ZXing.Net.Mobile uses ZXing.Net under the hood (an older version). ZXing.Net.Mobile adds some classes which make it easier to integrate into mobile scenarios. It would be great if the maintainer of ZXing.Net.Mobile would release a new version of the library built against the newest ZXing.Net assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem thanks to a post from Jarvan Zhang in xamarin forums:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/697849/generate-qr-code-in-xamarinandroid.html

**Jarvan Zhang:**
The ZXing.Net API may not perform well on Android. Try using the ZXing.Net.Mobile package instead, which is a mobile-specific. I've tested the code with this package, it works as expected. The nuget requires the Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 dependency, please install the package on the project.

I hope this helps someone who's experiencing the same problem.